# Finding Values in Python json.loads Dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm working with a REST API that returns data in the following format:

```
{
"id": "2902cbad6da44459ad05abd1305eed14",
"displayName": "",
"sourceHost": "dev01.test.lan",
"sourceIP": "192.168.145.1",
"messagesPerSecond": 0,
"messages": 2733,
"size": 292062,
"archiveSize": 0,
"dates": [
    {
        "date": 1624921200000,
        "messages": 279,
        "size": 29753,
        "archiveSize": 0
        },
        {
        "date": 1625007600000,
        "messages": 401,
        "size": 42902,
        "archiveSize": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using json.loads to successfully pull the data from the API, and I now need to search for a particular "date:" value and read the corresponding "messages", "size" and "archiveSize" values.

I'm trying to use the "if-in" method to find the value I'm interested in, for example:

```
response = requests.request("GET", apiQuery, headers=headers, data=payload)

json_response = json.loads(response.text)

test = 2733

if test in json_response.values():
    print(f"Yes, value: '{test}' exist in dictionary")
else:
    print(f"No, value: '{test}' does not exist in dictionary")
```

This works fine for any value in the top section of the JSON return, but it never finds any values in the "dates" sub-branches.

I have two questions, firstly, how do I find the target "date" value? Secondly, once I find that "sub-branch" what would be the best way to extract the three values I need?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you meant by `three values I need`.

Answer (score -1):

```
from json import load

def list_dates_whose_message_count_equals(dates=None, message_count=0):
  return list(filter(
    lambda date: date.get("messages") == message_count, dates
  ))


def main():
  json_ = {}
  with open("values.json", "r") as fp:
    json_ = load(fp)

print(list_dates_whose_message_count_equals(json_["dates"], message_count=279))
print(list_dates_whose_message_count_equals(json_["dates"], message_count=401))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Returns this

```
[{'date': 1624921200000, 'messages': 279, 'size': 29753, 'archiveSize': 0}]
[{'date': 1625007600000, 'messages': 401, 'size': 42902, 'archiveSize': 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Unfortunately, I just get an error from your code:

```
print(list_dates_whose_message_count_equals(json_["dates"], message_count=279))
NameError: name 'json_' is not defined
```